# ZipFile.OpenRead, Error: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: vb.net, zip

I am using the .net 4.5 framework to decompress some zip files.  I am decompressing zip files that are about 265 Megs, they decompress to about to 400 to 500 Megs but I am getting a .net error - There is not enough space on the disk.

There is plenty of disk space, was curious if anyone else has had this issue or have some advise - Note: I have considered this is a server issue and not the code.

My code is straight forward but I am posting in case someone sees anything.  The following is in VB.Net.

```
        Using archive As ZipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(file)
            For Each entry As ZipArchiveEntry In archive.Entries
                entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath & "\" & entry.FullName, True)
                fi = New FileInfo(fullPath & "\" & entry.FullName)
                logEntries.Add(fi.Length & vbTab & fi.LastWriteTime.Date & vbTab & fi.LastWriteTime.Hour.ToString("00") & ":" & fi.LastWriteTime.Minute.ToString("00") & vbTab & fi.Name)
                totalLength = totalLength + fi.Length
            Next
        End Using
```

Thanks.